# How can I show $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is one dimensional?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I have to show that the ring $A=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is one dimensional. I know this means that it contains no chains $P\subset P'\subset P''$ of prime ideals, but I really don't see where to begin. The only thing I can think of is Krull's height theorem, but applying it here would mean showing $A$ is principal, and I don't think it is. Or is it?

Comment: the thing is that for any non-zero ideal $I\subset A$ the ring $A/I$ is finite. To see it e.g. first show that $I$ contains a non-zero integer $n$ (e.g. for $0\neq c\in I$ set $n=|c|^2$) and then just notice that $A/nA$ is finite.

Comment: @user8268 Why does that imply $A$ is one dimensional?

Comment: @JackM Because every finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: @Starfall So therefore all ideals are maximal, and the only chains are of the form $0\subset P$?

Comment: @JackM Careful, it shows that all _non-zero prime ideals_ are maximal.

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting $A$ as $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+3)$, you are looking at a quotient of the two dimensional ring $\mathbb Z[x]$ by a prime ideal.